# Detecting if integer can be written as sum of given integers

Tags: php, algorithm

Supposing I'm having the constants 3,5,6,9,10. How can I detect how to write $n, which is the input, as a sum of these constants with the least number of terms?

Examples

```
$n=10, S=10
$n=18, S=9+9
$n=24, S=9+9+6
$n=27, S=9+9+9
$n=28, S=10+9+9
```

Thanks

Comment: What thoughts do you have on the solution so far?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Should this also be tagged homework?

Comment: I thought about dividing repeatedly from the greatest to the smallest, and if in the end I end up with the remainder 0, then it can be written as sum of the numbers on the stack.

However, it is not a good way, take for example $n=17. It would say 17=10+6, remainder 1. The right solution should be S=6+6+5

Comment: No, it's not a homework. I just oversimplified my problem so good, that it seems to be one :)

Actually, it's for an online payment system via SMS.

Comment: What about input values that cannot be represented by the sum of these constants? 0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 11, ...?

Comment: Re-read the title please :-)
If it can be written as a sum, fine, if not, go to another payment option.

Comment: Is performance an issue? How big could the inputs be?

Comment: Your problem reminds me of those problems which ask how to make $X using coins of a given denomination. I'm willing to bet a solution that kind of problem will apply to this one as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is another Python solution, but hopefully it's easy for you to convert to PHP (I would do it myself, but I'm no PHP expert - I'm sure you could do a better job of it). I've tried not to use any advanced Python funcitons, so that it is easier for non-Python readers to understand, but if some Python syntax is not clear, please just ask.

```
allowed = [3, 5, 6, 9, 10]
n = 28

solutions = [ None ] * (n + 1)
solutions[0] = []

for i in range(n + 1):
    if solutions[i] is None: continue
    for a in allowed:
        if i + a > n: continue
        if solutions[i + a] is None or len(solutions[i]) + 1 < len(solutions[i + a]):
            solutions[i + a] = solutions[i] + [a]

print solutions[28]
```

It works by starting from 0 and building up to the desired number, keeping a cache of the shortest solution seen so far for each possible total. It has a running time of O(n * a), where a is the number of different allowed values.

By the way, your answer to n=28 is wrong. It should be [9, 9, 10].

Update: here's my attempt at a PHP solution:

```
<?php
$allowed = array(3, 5, 6, 9, 10);
$n = 28;

$solutions = array();
$solutions[0] = array();

foreach (range(0, $n) as $i) {
    if (is_null($solutions[$i])) continue;
    foreach ($allowed as $a) {
        if ($i + $a > $n) continue;
        if (is_null($solutions[$i + $a]) ||
            sizeof($solutions[$i]) + 1 < sizeof($solutions[$i + $a])) {
            $solutions[$i + $a] = array_merge($solutions[$i], array($a));
        }
    }
}

var_dump($solutions[$n]);
?>
```

It gives the right answer, but please be aware that I'm not a professional PHP coder - I just looked up the equivalent functions in the PHP documentation.

Comment: Great, I'll try to digest it and eventually accept your solution.

Comment: Skeetch: I've had a go at converting it to PHP. See my updated answer.

Comment: This is a nice, short-and-simple algorithm. I have reposted a cleaned-up PHP implementation, more in line with PHP's idioms.

Answer (score 2):

This is Mark Byers' algorithm, rewritten using loop structures that are more familiar to PHP developers, and constructs that won't generate PHP notices. `$C` is your set of integers, `$S` the solutions.

```
$n = 28;
$C = array(3, 5, 6, 9, 10);
$S = array(array());

// if your set isn't sorted already, you have to call sort()
//sort($C);

for ($i = 0; $i <= $n; ++$i)
{
    if (!isset($S[$i]))
    {
        continue;
    }

    foreach ($C as $v)
    {
        if ($i + $v > $n)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (!isset($S[$i + $v])
         || count($S[$i + $v]) > 1 + count($S[$i]))
        {
            $S[$i + $v]   = $S[$i];
            $S[$i + $v][] = $v;
        }
    }
}

print_r($S[$n]);
```

Comment: Sure. By the way, I didn't mention it initially, but if you sort your set of integers in ascending order you can exit the inner loop early, instead of iterating over every possible combination. I have updated the code snippet above accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Two obvious approaches suggest themselves:

1. Write a series of linear equations,
   and solve to find various solutions.
   Choose one with the least number of
   terms.
2. Trial and error, starting
   with the largest terms first.

Answer (score 0):

Find all possible solutions for "S=3A+5B+6C+9D+10E" then choose the one with the most 0 values for A,B,C,D,E

Comment: Actually you want the a solution that minimizes `A+B+C+D+E`.  That's not necessarily on the has the most zero values ... is it?

Comment: Yes.  The right keywords for the original problem are "solving linear Diophantine equations".

This is a substantial research area and algorithms are not trivial. 

For example: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.47.408

Comment: @Stephen I think you misread the question, he wants the least terms possible, hence the most zeros is what he's after

Answer (score 0):

a rough sketch of an unscalable but correct solution (sorry, so far its only python ..):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import itertools, sys

pool = [3, 5, 6, 9, 10]

repeat, found, solutions = 1, False, set()

try: x = int(sys.argv[1])
except: x = 42

while not found:    
    for n in itertools.product(pool, repeat=repeat):
        s = sum(n)
        if s == x:
            solutions.add(n)
            found = True
            break
    repeat = repeat + 1

print solutions
```

would yield:

```
$ python 1850629.py 11
set([(5, 6)])

$ python 1850629.py 19
set([(9, 10)])

$ python 1850629.py 21
set([(3, 9, 9)])

$ python 1850629.py 42
set([(3, 9, 10, 10, 10)])
```

Comment: The post is tagged `PHP` just so you know :)

Comment: it's too late in my TZ .. should be reading a book || sleeping i guess .. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the excellent general answers already provided, bear in mind that if your set of values has certain properties, much more optimal solutions exist.

Specifically, if your solution is 'minimal' - that is, a single best solution exists for any value - then you can find the smallest number of elements using a 'greedy' algorithm: Simply add the largest value until the remainder is smaller than it, repeat with the next largest value, and so forth.

As an example, the denominations used for money in many countries are .01, .02, .05, .10, .20, .50, 1, 2, 5, .... This set is minimal, so you can just repeatedly add the largest valid denomination.

Answer (score -1):

NP-complete problem

[Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)